# facebook multi-friend selector( javascript SDK), counting number of friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Hi i just wanted to know, is there any way to know how many friends the user selects from the multi-friend selector generated by the following code.

```
function InviteFriends(){
     FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'come on man checkout my application.'});
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Facebook will send back the `request_ids` for all the requests sent. so the number of requests would equal the number of friends selected.

How to access the `request_ids` is described in this tutorial: [How To: Send An Application Request Using The Facebook Graph API](http://www.masteringapi.com/tutorials/how-to-send-an-application-request-using-the-facebook-graph-api/44/)

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Check out this application!',
    title: 'Send your friends an application request',
},
function (response) {
    if (response && response.request_ids) {
        // response.request_ids is what you need
    } else {
        alert('canceled');
    }
});
```