# check if user share on facebook application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, share, facebook-javascript-sdk

is it possible in an iframe applications check if the user share something successfully. may i get the request id if it is successfully shared so if it is shared i want to make the share button's visible false to that user and the user earns some points if the share is successfull

so is it possible to know and check it?

i am using c# but it is ok for javascript code

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook multi-friend selector( javascript SDK), counting number of friends](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5729987/facebook-multi-friend-selector-javascript-sdk-counting-number-of-friends)

Answer (score 0):

using the Javascript SDK you should be able to get that information.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'Your message here',
    title: 'App Request',
},
function (response) {
    if (response) {
        var numberSelected = response.to.length;
        var firstIdSelected = response.to[0];
    } else {
        alert('canceled');
    }
});
```